# Using OpenGL together with Qt Data Visualization

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, data-visualization

I'm trying to render a 3D bar graph using the Data Visualization library of Qt. The application I want to develop requires that bars that are in different ranges must be colored with a different color. To make things more concrete

1) Yellow if value <=5000

2) Red if value between 5001 and 15000

3) Blue if value above 15000

However Qt's libraries do not allow me to color the bars with different colors. The class QBar3DSeries has three different options for the color style.

1) Q3DTheme::ColorStyleUniform : All bars are colored with the same color. This is out of the question.

2) Q3DTheme::ColorStyleObjectGradient : All bars are colored with the same gradient. Again this is out of the question.

3) Q3DTheme::ColorStyleRangeGradient : This could be a temporary solution. The bars are colored according to the ratio of the value of an individual bar and the value of the highest bar. But here, the bars are displayed in gradients and more than one color is used and I just want one color for each bar. And it is based on the relationship to the largest value, not on the values I want to specify. (In this example 5000, 15000 and 20000)

Maybe I will need other methods to intervene in the process by which the system renders the graph. Can I use OpenGL to do this? (Which means a lot of work, I don't know much about OpenGL)
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can draw it with QML.

Comment: Learning enough OpenGL to solve this one problem would be a lot of work. If you can solve the problem with QML, or by breaking figured into multiple components, then I'd say that's the way to go.